# Как определить сколько вхождений элемента в двумерный массив Python

Tags: python, список

Условно, имеется список:

```
b = [['i', 'are', 'the', 'champignons'], ['we', 'are', 'the', 'champions'], ['champ', 'i']]
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как определить:
Сколько вхождений каждого элемента по порядку во весь список b (т.е. сколько например элементов i или are во всем списке b)? К примеру, нижеуказанный код очевидно неверный, т.к. он покажет только вхождение элемента i[0] во весь список (а нужно всех элементов), но еще интересует, почему выдается результат 0 вхождений, несмотря на то, что i[0] - это в нашем списке является i, а ее в общем списке 2 штуки.

```
for i in b:
    print(b.count(i[0]))
```

Пришлось преобразовывать двумерный список b в общий список и потом перебором без проблем все сделал, но понимаю, что это слабовато, т.к. приходится делать лишние движения с преобразованием списков, поэтому хочу узнать, как это можно сделать с исходным списком. При ответе учтите пожалуйста, что мой уровень начальный и ответ должен быть соответствующий, либо ответ может быть любой (для последующего изучения мной материала на эту тему), но с дублированием простого.

Comment: поместите сюда ваш рабочий код, пожалуйста

Comment: вот он весь мой код, я просто разбираю ситуацию, чтоб в будущем упростить эту работу. Так как уже не первый раз наткнулся на это, но не знаю, как сделать
b = [['i', 'are', 'the', 'champignons'], ['we', 'are', 'the', 'champions'], ['champ', 'i']]
for i in b:
    print(b.count(i[0]))

Comment: вы писали: "Пришлось преобразовывать двумерный список b в общий список и потом перебором без проблем все сделал", но неважно уже, вам и так отвечают

Answer (score 0):

Нужно просто внимательно разобраться с тем, что в чем нужно считать и в какой переменной что содержится.

Здесь

```
for i in b: # i - это, например, ['i', 'are', 'the', 'champignons']
    print(b.count(i[0]))
```

считается количество вхождений первого элемента каждого вложенного списка (`i[0]`)в общий список `b`. Очевидно, что это равно 0. Так как ни один вложенный список не равен `'i'`.

Поэтому нужно считать количество вхождений "i" в каждый вложенный список:

```
for lst in b:
    print(lst.count("i"))
```

Comment: хорошо, а как автоматизировать процесс, чтоб каждый элемент искало в общем списке? если элементов будет сотня, то я не смогу же для каждого индивидуально прописывать его поиск вхождения, да и даже если их будет 10 - это не актуально. 
И если искать в каждом вложенном списке, то, как будто, легче преобразовать все в один список (как я в итоге и сделал) и сразу по нему одному пробежаться, чем по каждому вложенному?

Comment: как вообще звучит задача: посчитать количество вхождений каждого "базового" элемента в глобальный список?

Comment: моя задача - определить как посчитать количество вхождений каждого элемента каждого подсписка в глобальный список. Задача, которую я решал, не важно как звучит, т.к. я ее решил уже своим способом, преобразовав двумерный список в один глобальный с определенным количеством элементов. Я просто хочу узнать, мой вариант с преобразованием всех подсписков в один единый возможно заменить чем-то или по трудозатратам и строкам кода получится то же самое?